# JSON.parse not working in code, but works fine in developer console

Tags: javascript, json

I have an angular $http post service which talks to a WCF service. The http post has a success handler:

```
.success(function (data) {
    var response = JSON.parse(data);
    var tsValid = response.Outcome;
    deferred.resolve(tsValid);
}
```

However, tsValid is always 'undefined'. If I add some console logging, i can see that "data" looks like this:

```
 "{\"Message\":\"Valid Timestamp\",\"Reference\":\"CheckTimestamp:Completed\",\"Outcome\":true,\"Data\":null,\"MessageCount\":0,\"MessageGUID\":null}"
```

Then "response" looks like this:

```
 {"Message":"Valid Timestamp","Reference":"CheckTimestamp:Completed","Outcome":true,"Data":null,"MessageCount":0,"MessageGUID":null}
```

So all JSON.parse did in the success handler was strip out the escape characters. When I then try to access response.Outcome, it is undefined.

However, if I open a command prompt and do the JSON.parse manually on the "data" variable, it correctly parses the JSON and I can access response.Outcome.

Any ideas why the JSON.parse does not work in the success handler?

**EDIT** - I have amended the console output to remove the "data:" and "response:" tags. They were added to the console log by me so i could identify which one was which.

Comment: tsValid is local to the success function. does it go undefined after the var statement

Comment: tsValid is undefined immediately after "var tsValid = response.Outcome;"

Comment: What if you log `typeof response`?

Comment: typeof response is "string"

Comment: There you go. Looks like the server somehow does a double-stringification. You need to use `var response = JSON.parse(eval(data));` or `var response = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data));`

Answer (score 0):

Under `response` you have key `data`, so you should call:

`var tsValid = response.data.Outcome;`

**EDIT**

Can you run this code, and paste logs?

```
.success(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    var response = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(response);
    var tsValid = response.Outcome;
    deferred.resolve(tsValid);
}
```

Comment: I have edited the post as there may be some confusion about the JSON

Comment: log for data was: "{\"Message\":\"Valid  Timestamp\",\"Reference\":\"CheckTimestamp:Completed\",\"Outcome\":true,\"Data\":null,\"MessageCount\":0,\"MessageGUID\":null}"

Comment: log for response was: {"Message":"Valid  Timestamp","Reference":"CheckTimestamp:Completed","Outcome":true,"Data":null,"MessageCount":0,"MessageGUID":null}

Comment: JSON.parse for data returns error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token`

Comment: JSON.parse("{\"Message\":\"Valid Timestamp\",\"Reference\":\"CheckTimestamp:Completed\",\"Outcome\":true,\"Data\":null,\"MessageCount\":0,\"MessageGUID\":null}")

Comment: This comment box is inserting 2 invisible spaces between "Data:" and "null". If you remove these, the parse works

Comment: Can you use ` characters in future to avoid such problems?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59661/discussion-between-michail-w-and-jonnyknowsbest).